# looping over function with multiple argument

Tags: python-3.x, loops

Beginning python user here. This seems like a simple question but I haven't been able to find an answer or at least recognize an answer.

I have a function as follows:

```
def standardize(columns, dictionary):
    for x in columns:
        df.iloc[:,x] = df.iloc[:,x].map(dictionary)
```

The function takes a list of columns and recodes all the values in that column according to the associated dictionary.

Rather than calling the function a dozen times for each list of columns and its associated dictionary:

```
standardize([15,19,27], dict1)
standardize([47,65,108], dict2)
standardize([49,53,55,90], dict3)
```

ideally I'd like it to loop over. a list of all the column lists and a list of all the dictionaries. something like:

```
for column_list in [[list1], [list2], [list3]]:
    standardize(column_list, associated_dictionary)
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Take a look at `zip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no need to loop when considering single replacement. You can use `applymap` instead:

```
col_list = [...]
df.iloc[:, columns] = df.iloc[:, columns].applymap(dictionary.get)
```

Now, for multiple sets, you can `zip` your column lists and dictionaries and iterate:

```
column_lists = [col_list1, col_list2, ...]
dictionaries = [dict1, dict2, ...]

for c, d in zip(column_lists, dictionaries):
    df.iloc[:, c] = df.iloc[:, c].applymap(d.get)
```